# Cannot clone git repository

Tags: git

My System is Windows 7. I downloaded git and Tortoise git. I know how to use git itself, but don't know how to set it up. 
I received repository info by email where I find an url to git repository through ssh protocol and also there is a text file containing rsa key. 
When I try to clone the remote repository to local folder it asks for password. But the people that gave me this info haven't provided me with a password.

What should I do? Ask them for a password or may be there is a way to generate it from this key in txt file?

Comment: What is the name of the file with the rsa key?

Comment: its name is similar to my name

Comment: It could be your private key, then you wouldn't need a password

Comment: But when I try to load this key through Tortoise gui when cloning  Pageant says "couldn't load this key(OpenSSH SSH-2 Private key)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It asks for a password because it cannot find the private key. Check that you copied the private key in the correct place in your setup. Once the private key will be found by git it will perform public key authentication (instead of password authentication) and the password will not be asked.

Comment: Ok. I found the way to load the key. It was SSH-2 key. And putty wanted SSH-1 one. So I used puttygen to convert that key to SSH-1. After that I successfully loaded it to Tortoise when cloning the repo.